# Does windows 10 have SSH already?

Tags: ssh, windows-10

I was trying to find out if I can use SSH in windows 10, there are many aricles from early this year saying windows 10 was going to include SSH in powershell, but I still can't use it in my windows 10. So does windows 10 support SSH already? or I still have to use third party apps like putty?

Comment: (September 2017) Yes, in the creators update, in Development mode only.  See here:  https://superuser.com/questions/1120133/ssh-server-on-windows-10-out-of-nowhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows does not currently have native SSH support (expected [early 2016](http://betanews.com/2015/10/23/at-last-microsoft-brings-openssh-to-windows/))

Some further reading [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2015/06/03/looking-forward-microsoft-support-for-secure-shell-ssh.aspx)

Comment: Worth pointing out given Microsoft has been tight lipped about native SSH so far, its entirely possible the plans were scrapped.

Comment: ssh is included in the "Linux services for Windows", which is only available if you are running Win10 preview builds. Hopefully it will launch in the normal, stable builds soon.

Comment: well, it looks like win10 now runs ssh service by default. I didn't do anything and I see it's listening on port 22 and I can connect to it using putty. Looks like they silently enabled it.

Comment: I have the same experience as Pavel.  I installed the Linux Subsystem for Windows some time ago, and I've been using it, but I didn't know it included an SSH *server*.  I only discovered it was running when I ran "netstat -a" and saw that port 22 was open.  I then tried to SSH to my Windows machine from a Linux PC, and voilà! it worked.

Comment: This is the last update I've seen: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2015/10/19/openssh-for-windows-update/.  There are lots of activities on the project's GitHub repo but no word on roadmap: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/commits/L1-Prod

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more complete answer as of last week:

The PowerShell team is continuing to work on a Windows OpenSSH implementation. Their active work can be seen in [this repository](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable) which is a fork from the root [openssh-portable repository](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable). You can see from the [commit history](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/commits/latestw_all) that the PowerShell team regularly merges upstream commits into their repository as well as adding their own commits.

As best I can tell [PowerShell/openssh-portable](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable) has only modified the [upstream code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable) by adding the following folders (and their contained source files) ~/contrib/win32, ~/regress/pesterTests and ~/regress/unittests/win32compat.

On December 19, 2016 the PowerShell team created a [pull request](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/pull/63) into the [openssh/openssh-portable repository](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable) which is still under review. The most recent activity on the pull request appears to be comments/commits on Jun 13, 2017.

The PowerShell team has a second repository, [PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH), where they make builds of [PowerShell/openssh-portable](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable) available. The [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) repo has a few commits of its own but is mostly a source copy from [PowerShell/openssh-portable](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable).

You can see the list of [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) releases [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases). The releases contain executable binaries of the common openssh commands. If you extract the binaries and then add their directory to your PATH variable you should be able to use them.

Comment: its SO nice to just shell out in Windows and use ssh, this is working great!! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you can do as an alternative is use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) for client side access.  If you want something server side, that is a bit harder.  But you could use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).  There are some articles to get its ssh daemon running as a windows service.